# XQuery FLWOR Expression with Multiple for-loops returns unexpected empty tags

Tags: xml-parsing, command-line-interface, xquery, flwor, xqilla

Here is a short version of my question.

When using a nested for-loop in a FLOWR expression returning the variable from the inner loop behaves as expected but returning the variable from the outer loop unexpectedly returns empty tags.

---

Here is a longer version of my question.

I have recently started learning XQuery. I've been using the XQilla command-line tool on Mac OS X 10.10.4 (Yosemite) to execute my XQuery scripts. In particular I've tried XQilla Version 2.3.0_2 which I installed with the MacPorts package manager and also XQilla version 2.3.2 which I manually installed from source.

While experimenting with various XPath and FLWOR expressions I came across an unexpected behavior which I've narrowed down to the simplified example which I am going to present here. The example consists of a single XML data file and two versions of a simple XQuery; the first query works as expected but the second query does not.

Here is my XML data file (`test.xml`):

```
<elements>

    <element>
        element data
    </element>

</elements>
```

Here is my first XQuery script (`test_1.xq`):

```
for $e1 in doc("test.xml")//element
    for $e2 in doc("test.xml")//element
        return $e1
```

And here is my second XQuery script (`test_2.xq`):

```
for $e1 in doc("test.xml")//element
    for $e2 in doc("test.xml")//element
        return $e2
```

Both queries consist of the same redundant, nested for-loops, but the first query returns the variable from the outer (i.e. first) for-loop and the second query returns the variable from the inner (i.e. second) for-loop. I expected the two queries to have similar output in general, and identical output for this specific data file, however that appears not to be the case.

Here is a sample shell session:

```
$ xqilla test_1.xq
<element>
        element data
    </element>

$ xqilla test_2.xq
<element/>
```

So returning the variable from the outer loop only produces the empty tag; this was unexpected.

As a sanity-check I tried a third variation (`test_3.xq`):

```
for $e1 in doc("test.xml")//element
    for $e2 in doc("test.xml")//element
        where $e1=$e2
        return $e2
```

And when I execute this third query I get:

```
$ xqilla test_3.xq
<element>
        element data
    </element>
```

I would have originally expected this query to work correctly, but in light of the unexpected behavior of `test_2.xq` I would think that `test_3.xq` would also fail. This only adds to my confusion.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Are you really sure `test_2.xq` contains the query posted here?

Comment: @JensErat I'm pretty sure; I just double-checked. I guess I'll submit a bug report. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: just a note: `<element/>` is not a closing tag. it is XML's short notation for an empty element, i.e. it is equivalent to `<element></element>`.

Comment: @dret Yeah, apparently I'm mildly dyslexic. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably a bug. An online XQuery tester http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery returns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<element>
        element data
    </element>
```

as a result for both scripts (with the `doc(...)` part removed).